# It is possible to point some specific subdomains to a DNS server using Wildcard subdomain?

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain, wildcard

Assuming `example.com` domain and fake IPs, the configuration needed is this:

- example.com points to `186.200.1.1`
- **www**.example.com points to `186.200.1.1`
- **adm**.example.com points to `186.200.1.1`
- **online**.example.com points to `186.200.1.2`
- **store**.example.com points to `186.200.1.3`
- ***.example.com** points to `186.200.1.5`

That is, we have two rules:

1. Subdomains **www, adm, online** and **store** have their specific servers.
2. Any subdomain of `example.com`, except **www, adm, online** and **store**, should
   point to `186.200.1.5` server.

It's possible archieve that using only DNS records?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is extremely possible!
If you add an A record for *.example.com, it will resolve all non-existent domain names to the specified IP address. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record

For example, if your records looked like this:

```
*.example.com -> 8.8.8.8
a.example.com -> 8.8.4.4
```

It would mean:

```
a.example.com resolves to 8.8.4.4
b.example.com resolves to 8.8.8.8
c.example.com resolves to 8.8.8.8
```

Sub-domains B & C were not specified, which is why they fall back on the wildcard record! :)

Comment: Ok @augrunt, there is a chance that the subdomain `a.example.com` matches with the wildcard rule even if it has own rule?

Comment: @Rodrigo As it says in the Wiki article: A wildcard DNS record is a record in a DNS zone that will match requests for **non-existent** domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like this:

```
*.example.com.           3600     A     192.0.2.1
```

It is important that the asterisk is the leftmost sub. The rest of those should be standard A records except for www and adm you could do a CNAME record if you want.